# Use of dbms_assert.noop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What is actual use of dbms_assert.noop ?
Since this function performs no error checking and returns the input string as it was entered.

Answer (score 3):

Read [here](http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00001154.htm) on Pete Finnigan's blog where he discusses the `dbms_assert.noop` function. it mentions:

> This (dbms_assery.noop), we can now clarify is used to mark a piece of code that is not to be tested by automated test tools (presumably Fortify) as this function does nothing except return the string passed unchanged.

By this, what I have understood that I can use this function where I am passing actual piece of code through a variable and I don't want it to be checked for SQL injection attacks.

This is one of the many uses of this function.